# adicionar um ouvinte no editText

Tags: android, edittext

como eu faço para fazer uma ação ser executada, toda vez que o usuário digitar alguma letra no editText, pesquisei mas não achei oque queria, se alguém souber pelo menos uma dica de como pesquisar já ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu EditText você faz adiciona o método `addTextChangedListener()` da seguinte forma:

```js
package genesysgeneration.svg;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                
                //aqui você executa uma determinada ação antes da modificação do editText
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                //aqui você executa uma determinada ação durante a modificação do editText

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                //aqui você executa uma determinada ação depois da modificação do editText

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Nele você tem 3 opções para a execução de uma ação, antes do edtText ser modificado, durante e depois. Você escolhe um dos três de acordo com a sua necessidade.